# Swift multidimensional array of textures

Tags: swift, animation, multidimensional-array, sprite-kit, sktexture

I am trying to load a bunch of animated textures from a texture atlas into an array but I get an error when trying to append a frame to the array.

Basically I want to have a multidimensional array of textures where each row represents an animation which is an array of frames. Something like this:

```
[[FirstFrameTexture, SecondFrameTexture, ThirdFrameTexture...], //first animation
 [FirstFrameTexture, SecondFrameTexture, ThirdFrameTexture...], //second animation
 [FirstFrameTexture, SecondFrameTexture, ThirdFrameTexture...]] //third animation
```

I initialised an array like this:

```
var animations = [[SKTexture]]()
```

but when I try to append a texture into the array like this

```
animations[0].append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "test"))
```

I get an error on this line saying:

```
fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first array, at index 0, isn't yet created when you try to append an animation to it.

First add an animation embedded in an array, for example:

```
animations.append([SKTexture(imageNamed: "test")])
```

Then you can add animations in the array:

```
animations[0].append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "test2"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that was the problem but I tried to add the first texture the wrong way using "animations.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "test"))", I didn't include the square brackets and therefor I was getting the "(SKTexture) is not identical to 'AnyObject'" error

Comment: This would be so much helpful if we could just append in a SKSpriteNode object.